# How to Store locally Increment Counter in ListView? flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am talking an API request from website And there is an vote which I would like to locally store in flutter. I already implemented increment & decrement of votes but I want to store that votes locally in the phone, in a flutter.

How to locally store increment & decrement counter in listView?

```
class MoviesModel {
  int vote;

MoviesModel({this.vote});

  int increaseCounter() {
    vote++;
    return vote;
  }

  void decreaseCounter() {
    if (vote > 0) {
      vote--;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the listView Builder

```
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _movies.length,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final moviess = _movies[index];


 return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_outlined,
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          final prefs = await SharedPreferences
                                              .getInstance();

                                          setState(() {
                                            final vote =
                                                moviess.increaseCounter();
                                            prefs.setInt('vote', vote);
                                            print(vote);
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                      // moviess.vote.toString(),
                                      Text(moviess.vote.toString() ?? " ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 20)),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            moviess.decreaseCounter();
                                          });
                                          // decreaseCount();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
}

),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
  Future<void> _storeIncrement(int yourValue) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('counter', yourValue);
  }
```

there is also more option to store as per your datatype as below

```
prefs.setBool(key, value)
prefs.setString(key, value)
prefs.setDouble(key, value)
prefs.setStringList(key, value)
```

below code is to get data

```
 Future<void> _getIncrement() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int storedValue = prefs.getInt('counter');
    print('your data is $storedValue');
  }
```

get data as per your datatype

```
prefs.getBool(key)
prefs.getString(key)
prefs.getDouble(key)
prefs.getStringList(key)
```

Comment: `await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` should only be called once to avoid re-initialising the instance again and again. Better to initialise it as early as possible.

Comment: @DarShan Is right, `SharedPreferences` instance should be called once to avoid reinitialise. But if you're confused or new then you can go for as I mentioned in above example

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).
2. Create a variable in your class as `SharedPreferences prefs;`
3. Initialise the instance in the `initState()` like: `prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()`
4. When the counter is clicked / increased / decreased, save it like this:
   `await prefs.setInt('counter', counterValue);`
5. When you open the app next time, check in the `initState()` if there is a value saved in preferences. If yes, then use that else use 0.
   Example:
   `int counter = (prefs.getInt('counterValue') ?? 0);`
   Now use this `counter` variable to display text.

Comment: so when you receive the votes from api, save them to sharedPreferences.